# Java: taking only the first word of a user input string

Tags: java, string

Homework question that I've been having a little trouble with...

I need to have a user input string as a product category. If the user inputs more than one word, I need to take only the first word typed.

Stipulation: I cannot use 'if' statements.

Here's what I have so far, but it fails if only one word is typed.

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);
System.out.println ("Enter a noun that classifies the"
                    + " type of your product:");

String noun = scan.nextLine();
int n = noun.indexOf(" ");
String inputnoun = noun.substring(0,n);
```

Comment: `String#split` - `String[] parts = noun.split(" ");` then the first element is the first word, regardless of whether there is actually multiple words or not...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use string.split()

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);
System.out.println ("Enter a noun that classifies the"
                    + " type of your product:");

String noun = scan.nextLine();
String inputnoun = noun.split(" ")[0];
```

Comment: You can also use `split(" ", 2)[0]` to avoid unnecessary splitting on rest of spaces.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `scan.next()` to get only the first word.

Comment: In case you would also want to consume rest of data from user to prepare Scanner for next word from new line simply add `scan.nextLine()` after `scan.next()`.

Answer (score 1):

The method `split(String regex)` in the string class will return an array of strings split on the regex string.

```
String test = "Foo Bar Foo Bar"
String[] array = test.split(" ");
//array is now {Foo, Bar, Foo, Bar}
```

From there you can figure out how to get the first word.

Next time you are stuck, the [Java API pages](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) are very helpful for finding new methods.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `String[] array = noun.split("\\s+")`, to split between the spaces, and then use `array[0]` to return the first word.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of manipulating the entire input String, another way is to use the `delimiter` of the `Scanner` class:

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

// Following line is not mandatory as the default matches whitespace
scan.useDelimiter(" ");      

System.out.println("Enter a noun that classifies the"
                    + " type of your product:");

String noun = scan.next();
System.out.println(noun);
```

Note that we are using `next()` instead of `nextLine()` of the Scanner class.

Comment: By default the `Scanner`'s delimiter is a whitespace, there is not need for `useDelimiter(" ");`

Comment: Indeed, I included that to emphasize the idea of using delimiter. I have already added this point in the comment of my code